# how to do runtime bean deployement and destroy a bean in spring ioc container?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, containers

I have an application which is having a `ClassPathXMLApplicationContext` which has loaded some beans from spring xml files.
I want to add a bean at runtime. So i created another instance of `ClassPathXMLApplicationContext` which reads the new bean definitions from new xml files. Now i have two appContexts.

My Question is: how do i copy the beans from the new context to the old context? is it necessary to copy? cant i just merge these two contexts? is there an api for merging?

Later i want to undeploy the bean a runtime. I also want classloader to unload the bean class when i delete the bean.

How to delete a bean from an ApplicationContext and also unload the bean class.

Thanks,
Regards,
Vimal

Comment: What is your expected behavior of spring when you add bean to the context: should spring recalculate the complete dependencies, or do you only need the additional features like transaction support, aop,... for that added/removed bean?

Comment: @Ralph i dont need the dependencies to be recalculated. just the new bean should be available in the container. so that others can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need second instance of ClassPathXMLAplicationContext. I think this will help you :

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");
Product myProduct = (Product) context.getBean("Batery");
//when you want to change the bean with another
myProduct = (Product) context.getBean("CD-RW");
```

In the XML file you need two beans where "Batery" could initialize with what you want, but "CD-RW" can't be initialized with constructor. Here is an example with setter initialize :

```
<bean id="Batery" class="com.seller.springtest1.Battery">
    <property name="name" value="AAA" />
    <property name="price" value="2.5" />
</bean>

<bean id="CD-RW" class="com.seller.springtest1.Disc">
    <property name="name" value="CD-RW" />
    <property name="price" value="1.5" />
</bean>
```

I don't get the aquestion about deletion(it's garbage collector function) if you have special needs(when you retained the myProduct reference) you could do myProduct = null

Comment: for the question about deletion, i will use your example. suppose i have loaded the "aaa" bean. Later i have a new version of the class "com.trader.springtest1.Battery" and i want the application to use the new version without restarting the JVM. so i want to delete the bean named "aaa", and then reload it with new class.  So in order got new Battery class to be loaded, the old Battery class must be unloaded by the class loader. else it will give object of the old class if i do `getBean("aaa")`

Comment: if i do `myProduc = null` will it also set the referece inside the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext'to be null? i think not. as my bean is a singleton bean, spring maintains a map inside the XMLBeanFactory. that reference will still exist.

Comment: just use
myProduct = null; 
myProduct = context.getBean("Batery");
The null will release retain count of myProduct to 0 and then retain it again.

Comment: Other way is to set destroy-method="someMethod" in the .xml file to do specific work when you destroy your object(but your method will be called when garbage collector sees that reference isn't needed any more)

Comment: thanks. but my requirement is not to 'do something' when object gets destroyed by the GC. It is to force its destruction on demand :)